# XSLT transform function failing due to special characters

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT function which is selecting data from a C# data table. If the column name of the table happens to contain special characters such as brackets then it’s causing the XSLT to fail as it I guess it thinks it’s calling a new function. If I put single quotes around the column name then XSLT selects the string within the single quotes and not the data contained in that column of the table.

E.g

```
<Data>
    <xsl:value-of select=”MyColumnName(WithBrackets)”/>
<Data>
```

Can anyone help
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The select expression needs to contain a valid XPath expression. XPath expressions select data from XML documents, not from "C# data tables" (whatever they might be). To help you with your enquiry, we need to know what your XML document looks like.